# Windows Phone 7 await inside foreach C# 5.0 Async

Tags: windows-phone-7, async-ctp, c#-5.0

I'm using the C# async CTP to call some remote functions that return me a URI, I have the following code:

```
 public async Task<Uri> GetUriAsync(string service, string endpoint)
    {


        Uri result = null;
        foreach (var service in _serviceProvider)
        {
            try
            {

                result = await service .GetAsync(service,endpoint);

                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Since there is a await inside the foreach, this method should return in the first await, but by debugging I noticed that when the code reachs the await it jumps to "return result"

I've used async ctp before (not on windows phone) and done code similar to this one.

What is wrong in that?

EDIT: This isn't the debugger error/bug, since the remote call is never done (I have a log in there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an internal exception at AsyncCtp dll. It seams that the debugger categorizes this exceptions as First Chance exception and decide not to abort the debug session. By doing the code runs normally but without doing the web request (in this case) leaving the developer to think that everything is ok.

Thanks for the help @Reed.

Comment: It's not the debugger that categorizes exceptions. If you turn off first chance exceptions notifications, you will be notified only of uncaught exceptions.

Comment: You are right, what i meant is that the debugger was "ignoring" this exceptions, leaving me unnoticed of them. If there are more people like me that debugs with the source at full screen, they would miss this since the debugger notifies this exceptions on the output tab.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that.  The debugging experience in the CTP is far from perfect.  It's improved, but still not perfect, in the VS 11 CTP.

At runtime, this should produce the results you're expecting (returning the first result that is not null).

Comment: Forget to say that, the value is returned causing a error on my code. No service is called . . .

Comment: @DVD The code *should* return a `Task<Uri>` immediately.  The Task won't complete until the service call completes, however...

Comment: correct, but what I'm seeing is the function returning and getting to the point where the result is validated, (if uri != null) and no service calls on my log

Comment: Uri imageUri = await ImageController.Instance.GetUriAsync( "imageServer", "jpgs");
if(imageUri == null)
   MessageBox.Show("ERROR");

Comment: I noticed now that in the output tab I'm getting this: first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll